# Possible Bug In Java Swing Timer Class

Tags: java, swing, timer, set, delay

**This has been answered in a comment**

It seems like setDelay doesn't affect the first run through of the timer?

output:

-1 second

done

-5 second

done

-5 second

done, etc...

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Timer test = new Timer(1000, new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            System.out.println("done");
        }
    });

    test.setDelay(5000);
    test.start();
    while(true);

}
```

Comment: When all else fails, read the instructions.  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#setDelay-int-

Comment: you are a genius. I was on
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#setDelay(int)

Comment: Well, maybe we can close this so others don't have to check again?

Comment: Solved by reading the [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/Timer.html#setDelay(int)), *"This does not affect the initial delay property, which can be set by the setInitialDelay method."*

Comment: Sorry, it is my first time posting. I think that since the answer was in the comments, I couldn't close the question.